# What is the function Modern_Spanish_CI used for in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, left-join, collate

What purpose would the following function be used for in SQL when specifying fields for a left outer join;

```
y.[ACCOUNT_ID] COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS= z.[ACCOUNT_ID] COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

Comment: What kind of "function" are you talking about? Can you share more details, like the system you are using and a valid SQL query?

Comment: . . . `collate` is not a function. It is kind of rules that gives direction to database engine how to compare and sort the character data.

Answer (score 1):

A collation defines the way strings are sorted and compared.

`COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` refers to the Modern Spanish collation, case-insensitive, accent-sensitiv, i.e. case is ignored, but accents are not ignored.

I don't know your data, but having an accent-sensitive `Account_ID` sounds "interesting" ;)

On the other hand, if the two `Account_ID` columns are defined with different collations, or the statement refers to temp tables, enforcing a common collation is reasonable, or even necessary, if the database-level or column-level collation deviates from the server-level collation.